# I want to change my light bulb to an LED multicolored light bulb

Tags: lighting, led

I want to change my current light bulb (which I believe to be a florescent, though I am unsure) in my bedroom to an LED one so I can make it change colors.

I am looking at buying this bulb:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/iLC-Colour-Changing-Control-Bayonet/dp/B072PQVG1X/ref=sr_1_11?keywords=led%2Bcolour%2Blight%2Bbulb&qid=1585699077&sr=8-11&th=1

However, I am not sure if it will work correctly as this is my first time buying a different type of bulb. I live in the UK.

I have attached an image of my current bulb below, thanks in advance for any help. I'll be happy to supply any further information if needed.

[image: My current light bulb]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Don't buy anything that attaches to mains power from Amazon, eBay or Banggood. It is cheaply made junk; they are using mail-order to circumvent UK product safety laws. I don't really care if you do that with things that run on battery power, but mains can kill you any of several ways.  (e.g. shorting out, burning and emitting toxic smoke that damages your immune system because they used the cheap plastic that BSI won't approve, and then your weakened immune system makes you not survive something else).

Answer (score 1):

I think the op did the shopping but wants to know if it will work.

Looking at the original lamp and the new one I would say yes they both work in the same voltage range.

In my area the bayonet style lamp is not used on mains voltage but it appears that it is for your area.

So yes it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your original light is a "CFL", which is a fluorescent tube with a built-in internal *ballast* (that's what's inside the weird lump).

Since the old one is rated for 220-240V, clearly that socket has bog-standard household 240V on it (and not 12V or some weird ballasted current intended for a particular tube).

So yes, you are G2G to install any safe, legal light which will fit that socket.   A safe, legal light will have

- a BSI stamp/certification, or TUV, CSA, UL or ETL mark.
- A CE mark *but only if sold at retail at a respectable bricks-n-mortar shop*
- Never something from eBay, Banggood or Amazon.   There are 2 problems with Amazon: This

[image]

(shipment from an Amazon warehouse counts the same as direct shipment from China; this is a dodgy foreign seller).   And this: products sold by Amazon *proper* can't be trusted because of [Amazon Commingling](https://www.riverbendconsulting.com/2019/08/23/amazon-fba-just-say-no-to-commingling-inventory/).  A counterfeiter dropships fakes to an Amazon warehouse and tells Amazon they're the same SKU as the genuine product. Amazon trusts them! And will commingle the fakes in the same bin. So even a trusted seller known to you, like Amazon *proper*, can ship counterfeits.  Worse, Amazon may stop reordering genuine product since they're well stocked on that SKU, so the fake takes over the bin.

So, assuming there isn't some sort of pandemic running around, just head down to Wickes or a proper lighting supply or other reputable seller, or buy from them online *if they do their own fulfillment in-house*.  And don't get snake-charmed by the low prices on the cheap Cheese.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, that's very good to know. I wasn't aware that Amazon Commingling was a thing. I ordered the bulb and it has a CE mark, a RoHS mark, and an FC mark, so it seems like it shouldn't be trusted. I think I will need to wait for Wickes to open again as i assume it is closed with everything that is going on at the moment.